# Rails, Canvas and Javascript - Convert image from Flickr to grayscale

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, canvas, activesupport

For a while I'm trying to convert an image hosted on Flickr to grayscale on the fly.

I've tried the `javascript/canvas` solution but got caught by the [same origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672643/html5-canvas-getimagedata-and-same-origin-policy).
For this there's the [$.getImageData](http://www.maxnov.com/getimagedata/) solution but since it depends on another server I thought it won't be very reliable.

I decided to try convert the images on the server side. Using Rails.

My first option is convert the images to base64 using [AciveSupport::Base64](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Base64.html) before displaying them on a `canvas` and then converting using javascript. That way I might trick the same origin policy. Just wondering how slow all this conversion will be every time someone loads the page.

The other option would be using something like [Rmagick](http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/) to do the trick. But I'm not sure if I can use RMagick without saving the converted image somewhere before linking it on my view.

Would be great to have some thoughts on this solutions since I'm a beginner and have no idea how wrong these implementations might be.

Answer (score 0):

Just do it on the server. Same origin policy forces you to use some sort of server anyway. Rmagick is ok, I've used it for color (histogram) analysis before. Maybe desaturation is a candidate for more optimized libraries.

As for serving the actual image, you don't need a file, the image itself is a separate GET command (action) that needs to be supported by your server. So it can just return data. That's not to say this is always the best approach.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to do it on the server. Do you have any suggestion for a library to handle desaturation?

Comment: No but you need the formula to turn RGB to HSB and then ignore the S value.

Answer (score 0):

Just posting here how I implemented the solution. I decided to create a kind of a proxy for the external images. This way I don't get caught on the same origin policy and can desaturate the images using `canvas` and `javascript` with one of the many scripts available.

On my view:

```
<%= image_tag "/proxy?url=#{photoset.flickr_thumb_url}", :class => "gray" %>
```

On my controller:

```
def image_proxy
  image_url = params[:url]
  image = open(image_url).read
  response.headers["Expires"] = CGI.rfc1123_date(Time.now + 1.day)
  send_data image, :filename => File.basename(image_url), :disposition => 'inline'
end
```

I'm just annoyed by the fact that any image that anyone pass using this url will work. It's not very secure, is it? I'm still trying to figure out a way to fix this. I'd appreciate any help.